# Slack Notification upload/attach log file

Tags: groovy, slack

I prepared a jenkins pipeline under which if any step fails, Jenkins then send notification on respective slack channel with the link containing Job Console output URL. What I am planning is to get output logs and send them as a attachment to the channel if job fails somewhere in between but not the URL (I don't want anybody to login to jenkins to check logs).

Currently what I am doing is (working fine):

```
    stage ('1- Pull SourceCode')
    {
        try
        {
            node
            {
                print "Test SVN Checkout"
                //checkout command
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
            slackSend (channel: '#channelname', color: '#FF0000', message: "Stage 1 Failed : check  error logs at ${env.JOB_URL}" , teamDomain: 'xyz', token: 'token')
        }
    }
```

Could somebody help me with slackSend command which picks the log file from some location and send it as an attachment to the channel.
Or 
slackSend command to send pipeline **stage** logs as attachment to slack channel.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code where you can pass the jenkins console log or refer to the URL:https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/slack/

```
#!/bin/groovy

def jenkinsConsoleUrl = "$env.JOB_URL" + "$env.BUILD_NUMBER" + "/consoleText"
node('mynode') {
    stage("Build") {
        def attachments = ""
        "[ { \"text\": \"And here’s an attachment!\" } ]"
        ""
        echo(attachments)
        slackSend(channel: "channel_name", color: "colorcode", message: "Test message" + jenkinsConsoleUrl, attachments: attachments)
    }

}
```